# Activity Recognition returning stale activity

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I am currently writing an app that uses the Google's Activity Recognition API, however in my onHandleIntent method when I put a break point in there to examine the intent being passed in from the service, it is showing me stale data. The activity is returning as STILL even though I am on the road and even on the freeway. [FYI I am not driving but in a moving vehicle :) ] is there anyway to flush the results? even when I disconnect and reconnect I am still getting this STILL reading.

Comment: were you able to solve this, as it seems that I have the same issue with no solution

Comment: What I have noticed is for some reason my location services becomes disabled. When thus happens the STILL reading makes sense. Currently I am looking into a work around thst will alert the user that the location has been disabled and I am also trying to monitor if when the data become stale that it is in fact the location services is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share this on the off chance that it is a partial solution to the issue I described in my question. I have tweaked my code and it appears to not be having this issue at the moment. What I am doing to the intent being passed to the activity recognition is giving it a dynamic id, my theory is if i disconnect and reconnect it will is getting the same code to it maybe be caching the stale state. Now with my dynamic id, which really shouldn't hurt anything b/c the id only changes after the remove updates is called, I am hoping this will prevent the cached state.

```
 private static void intentID(){
    if(intentID == 0)
        intentID = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return intentID;
}

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, intentID(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//the modified pendingIntent being used
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(getActivityRecognitionClient(), 1000*10, pendingIntent)
```

hope this helps!